# Tensorflow Lite Image Classification always return the same output for different picture

Tags: android, kotlin, tensorflow-lite

So, I'm creating an app that is able to scan a product and display the name of the product. For example, if I scan a bottle of Coca-Cola, my app will display Coca-Cola. I use Image Classification and Data Augmentation to avoid overfitting. When I try my model in Google Collab, my model can predict the true output from an image input. But, when I convert the model into TensorflowLite, my app keeps returning the same probability of every image input. Does anyone know how to solve this?

This is my model:
https://github.com/SuperScanDev/SuperScan/blob/ML/ML_Model.ipynb

This is my Tensorflow Lite:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f1ud1ZEIIe6Phh4TruHwoTJjbddGFvx6/view?usp=sharing

This is my CameraActivity:

```
package com.pemeluksenja.superscan

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.WindowInsets
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.camera.core.*
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.pemeluksenja.superscan.databinding.ActivityCameraBinding
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

class CameraActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityCameraBinding
    private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService

    private var cameraSelector: CameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA
    private var capture: ImageCapture? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityCameraBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
        cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

        binding.captureImage.setOnClickListener {
            takePhoto()
        }

        startCamera()

    }

    private fun takePhoto() {
        val imageCapture = capture ?: return
        val photoFile = UriUtils.createFile(application)

        val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile).build()
        imageCapture.takePicture(
            outputOptions,
            ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
            object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
                override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@CameraActivity,
                        "Gagal mendapatkan gambar",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }

                override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                    val intent = Intent(this@CameraActivity, ResultScanActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("picture", photoFile)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            }
        )

    }

    public override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        hideSystemUI()
        startCamera()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        cameraExecutor.shutdown()
    }

    private fun startCamera() {

        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
            val preview = Preview.Builder()
                .build()
                .also {
                    it.setSurfaceProvider(binding.viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
                }

            capture = ImageCapture.Builder().build()

            try {
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    this,
                    cameraSelector,
                    preview,
                    capture
                )

            } catch (exc: Exception) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@CameraActivity,
                    "Gagal memunculkan kamera.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

    private fun hideSystemUI() {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            window.insetsController?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
        } else {
            window.setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            )
        }
        supportActionBar?.hide()
    }
}
```

This is my UriUtils.kt:

```
package com.pemeluksenja.superscan

import android.app.Application
import android.content.ContentResolver
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.graphics.Matrix
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Environment
import java.io.*
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*


private const val FILENAME_FORMAT = "dd-MMM-yyyy"

class UriUtils {
    companion object {
        private val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat(
            FILENAME_FORMAT,
            Locale.US
        ).format(System.currentTimeMillis())

        private fun createCustomTempFile(context: Context): File {
            val storageDir: File? = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
            return File.createTempFile(timeStamp, ".jpg", storageDir)
        }

        fun createFile(application: Application): File {
            val mediaDir = application.externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull()?.let {
                File(it, application.resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).apply { mkdirs() }
            }

            val outputDirectory = if (
                mediaDir != null && mediaDir.exists()
            ) mediaDir else application.filesDir

            return File(outputDirectory, "$timeStamp.jpg")
        }

        fun rotateBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap, isBackCamera: Boolean = false): Bitmap {
            val matrix = Matrix()
            return if (isBackCamera) {
                matrix.postRotate(180f)
                Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    bitmap,
                    0,
                    0,
                    bitmap.width,
                    bitmap.height,
                    matrix,
                    true
                )
            } else {
                matrix.postRotate(-180f)
                matrix.postScale(-1f, 1f, bitmap.width / 2f, bitmap.height / 2f)
                Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    bitmap,
                    0,
                    0,
                    bitmap.width,
                    bitmap.height,
                    matrix,
                    true
                )
            }
        }

        fun uriToFile(selectedImg: Uri, context: Context): File {
            val contentResolver: ContentResolver = context.contentResolver
            val myFile = createCustomTempFile(context)

            val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(selectedImg) as InputStream
            val outputStream: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(myFile)
            val buf = ByteArray(1024)
            var len: Int
            while (inputStream.read(buf).also { len = it } > 0) outputStream.write(buf, 0, len)
            outputStream.close()
            inputStream.close()

            return myFile
        }

        fun reduceFileImage(file: File): File {
            val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.path)

            var compressQuality = 100
            var streamLength: Int

            do {
                val bmpStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, compressQuality, bmpStream)
                val bmpPicByteArray = bmpStream.toByteArray()
                streamLength = bmpPicByteArray.size
                compressQuality -= 5
            } while (streamLength > 1000000)

            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, compressQuality, FileOutputStream(file))

            return file
        }
    }
}
```

This is my ResultScan Activity:

```
package com.pemeluksenja.superscan

import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import com.pemeluksenja.superscan.UriUtils.Companion.rotateBitmap
import com.pemeluksenja.superscan.databinding.ActivityResultScanBinding
import com.pemeluksenja.superscan.ml.SuperScan
import org.tensorflow.lite.DataType
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.TensorImage
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer.TensorBuffer
import java.io.File

class ResultScanActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityResultScanBinding
    private var getFile: File? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityResultScanBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val myFile = intent.getSerializableExtra("picture") as File
        getFile = myFile
        val result = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getFile?.path)

        //load file txt
        val fileName = "List Barang.txt"
        val inputString = application.assets.open(fileName).bufferedReader().use{it.readText()}.split("\n")

        var resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(result, 600, 600, true)
        val model = SuperScan.newInstance(this)
        var tbuffer = TensorImage.fromBitmap(resized)
        var byteBuffer = tbuffer.buffer

        // Creates inputs for reference.
        val inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, 300, 300, 3), DataType.FLOAT32)
        inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer)

        // Runs model inference and gets result.
        val outputs = model.process(inputFeature0)

        val outputFeature0 = outputs.outputFeature0AsTensorBuffer

        var max = getMax(outputFeature0.floatArray)

        binding.resultPredict.text = inputString[max]
        // Releases model resources if no longer used.

        for (i in 0..49){
            Log.d("Hasil", outputFeature0.floatArray[i].toString() + "" + inputString[i])
        }
        Log.d("qwwqd", outputs.toString())


        model.close()

        binding.imgResultScan.setImageBitmap(result)
    }

    private fun getMax(arr:FloatArray) : Int{
        var ind = 0;
        var min = 0.0f;

        for(i in 0..49)
        {
            if(arr[i] > min)
            {
                ind = i
                min = arr[i]
            }
        }
        return ind
    }

}
```

Everytime I tried to scan a product, my app keep returning this exact probability:

```
2022-06-08 22:21:14.252 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 0.0020250683 + ABC Sardines Saus Tomat
2022-06-08 22:21:14.252 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 0.105247945 + Bagus 50 Gr 2 Pcs Sibiru Pembersih Kloset
2022-06-08 22:21:14.252 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 0.15723251 + Bango Kecap Manis 550ml
2022-06-08 22:21:14.252 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 3.1695057E-5 + Bayfresh Pop Scent Pretty
2022-06-08 22:21:14.252 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 0.003600032 + Baygon Wangi Flower Garden
2022-06-08 22:21:14.253 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 0.0017373407 + Biore Body Foam Lovely Sakura
2022-06-08 22:21:14.253 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 0.009663447 + Blue Band Serbaguna 200g
2022-06-08 22:21:14.253 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 0.013563716 + BonCabe level 10
2022-06-08 22:21:14.253 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 0.031636655 + Carasun Solar Smart UV Protector 30 ml
2022-06-08 22:21:14.253 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 2.9004388E-5 + Choco Pie Marshmallow
2022-06-08 22:21:14.253 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 1.0112925E-5 + CLEAR Hijab Pure 300ml
2022-06-08 22:21:14.253 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 3.7141924E-4 + Coca Cola 1.5 L
2022-06-08 22:21:14.253 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 0.15753706 + Dandang Jasmine Tea
2022-06-08 22:21:14.254 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 6.0292064E-7 + Garnier Micellar Water
2022-06-08 22:21:14.254 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 7.8503723E-4 + Gery Bischoc
2022-06-08 22:21:14.254 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 9.25822E-4 + Jawara Saus Sambal
2022-06-08 22:21:14.254 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 0.01408089 + Johnsons Baby Blossom Soap
2022-06-08 22:21:14.254 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 3.407012E-4 + Kecap Inggris Asia Harum Sedap 135 ml
2022-06-08 22:21:14.254 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 2.9011096E-6 + Konicare Gel Pembersih Tangan
2022-06-08 22:21:14.254 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 0.012090961 + Kraft Cheddar
2022-06-08 22:21:14.254 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 0.0018850616 + La Fonte Spaghetti
2022-06-08 22:21:14.254 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 0.09647515 + Larutan Cap Badak Kaleng Rasa Leci 320 ml
2022-06-08 22:21:14.254 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 0.010348698 + Maestro Mayonais
2022-06-08 22:21:14.255 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 8.523392E-7 + Makarizo Hair Energy 100 ml
2022-06-08 22:21:14.255 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 1.3041635E-5 + Mamasuka Bumbu Instan Rendang
2022-06-08 22:21:14.255 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 0.0035436593 + Mie Telor Cap Ayam 2 Telor
2022-06-08 22:21:14.255 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 0.04495888 + Minyak Kayu Putih Cap Lang 210ml
2022-06-08 22:21:14.255 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 4.2212443E-5 + Miranda Hair Color Dark Brown
2022-06-08 22:21:14.255 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 9.162588E-5 + Nescafe Latte
2022-06-08 22:21:14.255 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 0.1535439 + Nuvo Active Clean Charcoal
2022-06-08 22:21:14.255 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 0.02530542 + Nuvo Antiseptic Wet Wipes Original
2022-06-08 22:21:14.255 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 0.044549614 + Polytex Sabut Spon Anti Gores
2022-06-08 22:21:14.256 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 1.2096439E-6 + Pringles Cheesy Cheese
2022-06-08 22:21:14.256 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 1.4766971E-6 + Rojukiss Jeju Lotus Serum
2022-06-08 22:21:14.256 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 7.5083395E-4 + Sabun Lifebuoy Cool Fresh
2022-06-08 22:21:14.256 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 0.0028604802 + Sania Tepung Terigu
2022-06-08 22:21:14.256 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 2.6599327E-4 + Sasa Santan Kelapa
2022-06-08 22:21:14.256 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 2.2436175E-6 + Selsun Gold 125 ml
2022-06-08 22:21:14.256 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 5.16566E-6 + Shinzui Lightening Soap
2022-06-08 22:21:14.256 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 9.1815565E-4 + Sidomuncul Este Emje + Gingseng Original
2022-06-08 22:21:14.257 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 5.4553687E-4 + Siip Nabati
2022-06-08 22:21:14.257 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 1.2350186E-5 + Skin Aqua UV Whitening Milk
2022-06-08 22:21:14.257 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 9.301124E-4 + So Klin Lantai Citrus Lemon
2022-06-08 22:21:14.257 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 0.0184359 + Sunlight 2in1 Krim+Bubuk Pembersih
2022-06-08 22:21:14.257 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 1.6269063E-6 + Teh Sosro Celup
2022-06-08 22:21:14.257 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 0.001788843 + Totole Kaldu Jamur 80g
2022-06-08 22:21:14.257 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 0.023943432 + Van Houten Cocoa Powder
2022-06-08 22:21:14.257 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 1.3248906E-5 + Vaseline Healthy Bright
2022-06-08 22:21:14.257 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 0.05784654 + Wipol Karbol Cemara
2022-06-08 22:21:14.258 10472-10472/com.pemeluksenja.superscan D/Hasil: 5.6936333E-6 + YOU Tone Up UV
```

Please help me:(

Comment: Have you tried debugging with dummy File(s)... not image taken from camera...

Comment: @HaseebHassanAsif Before I convert the model to Tensorflow Lite, Yes. But after I convert it to Tensorflow Lite, no. Is this important? Because the accuracy is pretty high before I convert the model to Tensorflow Lite, that's why I didn't test with dummy files after I convert it to Tensorflow Lite

Comment: It would narrow down the possible problems.

Comment: @HaseebHassanAsif If I used the exact same dummy files that I used to test the model (before I convert it to tensorflow lite) but the result is still the exact same, does that mean that my tensorflow lite is wrong?

Comment: if the result of the trained model changes on the same dummy images after tensorflow lite then it is a tensorflow lite issue. if your trained model gives wrong probabilities before importing it in tensorflow lite then it could be a training issue. if dummy data works fine after tensorflow lite but image taken from camera results in wrong probability then it could be that either your model is underfit or overfit or your camera image is not being parsed correctly